# Scala-I got the same amount of cipher with differnent amount of plaintext

Tags: scala, encryption, rsa

Listing below is my code

```
import java.security._
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec
import javax.crypto._
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import java.util.logging.Logger

object RSA {
   def bytes2hex(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = {
    val hex = new StringBuilder()
    for (i <- 0 to bytes.length - 1) {
      val b = bytes(i)
      var negative = false
      if (b < 0) {
        negative = true
      }
      val inte = Math.abs(b)
      val temp = Integer.toHexString(inte & 0xFF)
      if (temp.length() == 1) {
        hex.append("0")
      }
      // hex.append(temp.toLowerCase())
      hex.append(temp)
    }
    hex.toString
  }



def decodePublicKey(encodedKey: String):Option[PublicKey] = { 
    this.decodePublicKey(
      (new Base64()).decode(encodedKey)
    )   
  }
def decodePublicKey(encodedKey: Array[Byte]): Option[PublicKey]= { 
    scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch.opt {
      val spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey)
      val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
      factory.generatePublic(spec)
    }   
  }

def encrypt(file: String,key:PublicKey): Array[Byte] = { 

val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)

val text = Source.fromFile(file)

val list=text.toList

val blocks=list.grouped(501)

val iter=blocks.formatted()


val words=iter.getBytes

cipher.doFinal(words)
}

def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
val publicKey=decodePublicKey("--4096bits RSA public keys--")

val cipher = encrypt("E:\\plaintext.txt",publicKey.get)

println("Cipher is "+  bytes2hex(cipher))

}
  }`
```

Here the plain text("E:\plaintext.txt") I'd like to encrypt is about 1 Mb.  The max length of RSA keys is 4096 bits and the max size it can encrypt is 501 bytes. I decided to divide my text into 2093 arrays(1024*1024/501=2092.1)

I changed the plain text(E:\plaintext.txt) and the amount of the plain text changed as well. But I got the same amount of cipher with two different amounts of plain text.Anyone who can help me?

Comment: **Never use RSA as a block cipher**.  You should be using AES instead.

Comment: *"I got the same amount of cipher even the amount of plain text is changed"* - Can you give some examples? Please [edit] your question to include them. I know what it could be, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sure，I change the plain text (E:\\plaintext.txt）which is 1 Mb currently.The next plain text which I put out here is 2 Mb .However,the two different amounts of plain text got the same  amount of cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Use symmetric encryption such as AES to encrypt data.

If you need a public/private key pair encrypt the symmetric (AES) key with asymmetric encryption (RSA). Then package the AES encrypted data and RSA encrypted key as a unit.  This is commonly known as hybrid encryption and is in essence how HTTPs works.